# asp.net querystring returns null

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have a aspx page where I build an static url (.shtml) and at the end append it with ?id=1.

when I try to capture this querystring on load it returns null.

if I do same procedure to aspx file it returns the querystring.

```
<a href="<%#GetSEOUrl(Eval("ID")) %>" ><img 
    align="left" src="../../App_Themes/default/assets/images/v.png" /></a>

public string GetSEOUrl(object ID)
{
    //get url from db which will look like /directory/page.html
    structtest valRes = objRes.GetRow(ID);
    string r = Request.QueryString["r"];
    return Functions.getSiteUrl() + valRes.SEOURL + "?R=" + ;
}
```

then on my load page i get the querystring :

```
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)this.Master.FindControl("lnkMasterLink");

if (Request.QueryString["r"] != null)
{
    lnk.PostBackUrl = "lastpage.aspx";
}
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code we aren't mind readers.

Comment: I might be missing something, but your initial QueryString is `id`, not `r`, if you're appending `?id=`.

Comment: it is very confusing, there are **r** , **R** and **id** which one actually you using??

Comment: no get seourl is a method which I call from html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
va id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

keys are case sensitive.

Comment: I set my querystring here ::: return Functions.getSiteUrl() + valRes.SEOURL + "?R=" + ; so why id?

Comment: because the OP was miss leading. I thought the query string was id not R.